# Benchmarking mmap and output of /usr/bin/time, htop and the like

Tags: linux, benchmarking, memory-mapped-files, page-fault

I have a program which makes heavy use of memory mapping files into virtual memory, in particular files much larger than physical memory.

The performance of the program is not exactly brilliant. Given the setup, major page faults may be the culprit.

So I want to find out how bad this can be and wrote a program to estimate the impact of a major page fault. Basically I mmap a several GB size file and read some number of random bytes while measuring the time it takes to read the byte.

I can nicely see a huge difference in overall running time as well as cumulated or histogram-analyzed access times depending on whether the file is likely not in the cache (echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches), and when it is already in the caches in a second run of the test program.

In addition I look at the output of `/usr/bin/time -v` but these numbers are confusing (some lines clipped for brevity):

```
User time (seconds): 0.66
System time (seconds): 3.66
Percent of CPU this job got: 3%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 2:17.00
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1593920
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 7672
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 93641
File system inputs: 5094600
File system outputs: 200
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Can anyone answer the following questions:

1. A page has 4k and I have 7672 major page faults. These are a meager 30MB. It should not take over 2 minutes to page them in, even if on an (otherwise quite fast) smb file system.
2. What is meant by 'File system inputs'? The program does not do any file system input. It has mapped this 2.8 GB file, but it does no read(). Is this the number of reads or is it in kB? Does it relate in any way to the major page faults?
3. The close to 100k minor page faults nicely align with the 100k probes (single byte reads) the program takes. On this machine I actually can not drop_caches, I have to run the program on a different file to try to push out the data. I may not have worked. This might explain that I have mostly minor page faults. But why does this take so long. A blunt estimate of 2:17 minutes by 100k probes yields 1.37 milliseconds. Is this a "normal" order of magnitude for minor page faults?

EDIT: I just tried one more thing. I ran the test program again and record all system calls with strace. All I see is clock_gettime, gettimeofday, futex during the probing. No read(2) at all, so I wonder even more how the 'file system inputs', major and minor fault numbers provided by /usr/bin/time relate to each other.